# type 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'double'

Tags: flutter, dart

My goal is to calculate the place's average. However, I receive this error when I try to calculate:

type 'Future' is not a subtype of type 'double'

The expected was a double type because who would receive this would be a RatingBar.

Here's the function code:

```dart
calculateEvaluations() async{
    double average = 0;
    var docs = await Firestore.instance.collection(widget.option).document(widget.document.documentID).collection("comments").getDocuments();
    List<DocumentSnapshot> documents = docs.documents;
    for(int i=0; i<documents.length; i++){
      average = average + documents[i]["rating"].toDouble();
    }

    average = average / documents.length;
    return average;

  }
```

I set this return to the RatingBar.

```dart
Container(
  margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 5.0),
  child: RatingBarIndicator(
  rating: calculateEvaluations(),
  itemPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 2.0),
  itemBuilder: (context, index) => Icon(
    Icons.star,
    color: Colors.yellow,
  ),
  itemCount: 5,
  itemSize: 18.0,
    direction: Axis.horizontal,
  ),
),
```

Comment: Once toi define calculateEvaluations as an asynchrone function it becomes a Future<double>, not a double. You should **await** it to use it a a double, in other terms, you should wait for the future to resolve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I have done:

create a field `_ratingIndicator=0.0` of type `double` inside a class which inherits a `StatefulWidget`

```
void calculateEvaluations(){
    double rating=0.0,average = 0.0;
    int i;
    Firestore.instance.collection("y").document("x").collection("comments").getDocuments()
    .then((documents){
        for(i=0; i<documents.length; i++){
            rating = rating + documents[i]["rating"].toDouble();
        }
        average=rating/documents.length;
        setState(() {
         _ratingIndicator=average; 
        });
    });
  }
```

And,

```
Container(
  margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 5.0),
  child: RatingBarIndicator(
  rating: _ratingIndicator,
  itemPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 2.0),
  itemBuilder: (context, index) => Icon(
    Icons.star,
    color: Colors.yellow,
  ),
  itemCount: 5,
  itemSize: 18.0,
    direction: Axis.horizontal,
  ),
)
```

Also please don't forget to call the `calculateEvaluations()` in the `initState` method.

Hope this helps. I haven't tried it. Let me know if something went wrong.

Comment: Glad to hear that.